# Discord Bot to give role depending on the years member has been in server while excluding some members

Tags: python, discord, scripting, bots

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

TOKEN = 'Token'
GUILD_ID = GUILD_ID  
EXCLUDED_ROLE_NAME = ['Contractor',
                      'Allies',
                      'Ambassador',
                      'Other Org member',
                      'Civilian',
                      'Temp access'
                      ]
NEW_ROLE_NAMES = {
    1: '1st Year in Service',
    2: '2nd Year in Service',
    3: '3rd Year in Service',
    4: '4th Year in Service',
    5: '5th Year in Service',
    6: '6th Year in Service'

}

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user.name}')


@tasks.loop(hours=24)  # Check once per day
async def check_member_duration():
    guild = bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
    if guild:
        excluded_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=EXCLUDED_ROLE_NAME)
        if excluded_role is None:
            print(f"Error: Role '{EXCLUDED_ROLE_NAME}' not found.")
            return

        for member in guild.members:
            excluded_roles = [role for role in member.roles if role.name in EXCLUDED_ROLE_NAME]
            if not excluded_roles:
                join_date = member.joined_at
                if join_date:
                    membership_duration = datetime.now() - join_date
                    for years, role_name in NEW_ROLE_NAMES.items():
                        if membership_duration >= timedelta(days=365 * years):
                            new_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role_name)
                            if new_role and new_role not in member.roles:
                                await member.add_roles(new_role)
                                print(f'{member.name} has been given the role: {role_name}')


@bot.command(name='start_check')
async def start_check(ctx):
    check_member_duration.start()
    await ctx.send('Member check started.')


@bot.command(name='stop_check')
async def stop_check(ctx):
    check_member_duration.stop()
    await ctx.send('Member check stopped.')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

i am trying to make a discord Bot script to give role depending on the years (1-6 years) member has been in server while excluding some members (people who are in the server but not signed up as a member of the group)

The bot Connects to the server and i am able to start the script but when i do it tells me this

```
We have logged in as Sante Interstellar Solutions
Error: Role '['Contractor', 'Allies', 'Ambassador', 'Other Org member', 'Civilian', 'Temp access']' not found.
```